# Shell script to set screen resolution values in a file

Tags: macos, shell, sh

I want a shell script that

1. grabs my current screen resolution, **(solved)**
2. searches a file for the line containing the resolution setting,
3. replaces the old resolution setting in the file with the current one

So far (thanks!) I've got the command for getting the current screen resolution data:

```
system_profiler SPDisplaysDataType | awk '/Resolution/ {
    print "screenwidth \""$2"\"";
    print "screenheight \""$4"\"";
}'
```

The lines that should be written to respectively begins with:

```
screenwidth "VALUE1"
screenheight "VALUE2"
```

**How do I write the results to the file on the "VALUE" positions?**

(I'm quite a beginner in the world of shell scripts)

Comment: Do not pipe `grep` to `awk`.  Ever.  Instead of `grep Resolution | awk '{print $2}'`, do `awk '/Resolution/{ print $2 }'`

Comment: Alright thank you, I'll update that part!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood you right,

```
sys..|grep..|awk ..$2   is new widht
sys..|grep..|awk ..$4   is new height
```

you want to replace value1/2 in old file with new values from above lines

```
-- old file  --
screenwidth "VALUE1"
screenheight "VALUE2"
```

then you could do in one shot:

```
sys..|grep..|awk 'NR==FNR{w=$2;h=$4;next}/screenwidth/{$0="screenwidth \""w"\"";} /screenheight/{$0="screenheight \""h"\""}1' -  oldfile
```

see this test example:

```
#I simulate your sys..|grep.. with echo

kent$  cat old.txt
foo
screenwidth "VALUE1"
screenheight "VALUE2"
bar

kent$  echo "foo 200 bar 400"|awk 'NR==FNR{w=$2;h=$4;next}/screenwidth/{$0="screenwidth \""w"\"";} /screenheight/{$0="screenheight \""h"\""}1' -  old.txt    
foo
screenwidth "200"
screenheight "400"
bar
```

Comment: Since the others pointed out grep isn't needed I updated the resolution-getting line, how do I use it with the updated? (awk '/Resolution/)

Comment: Above doesn't matter to me really, but how do I write the results to the actual file? This leaves me with a print-out.

Comment: " > oldfile " instead of " -  oldfile" just writes the file empty.

Comment: @yusf redirect the output to file. Like awk... > file

Comment: @Kant Renders file empty though. :S

Comment: Oh of course, sorry. Thing is, it's suppose to write back to the same file! :)

Comment: Oh buddy,  ....awk...- old> /tmp/tmp && mv /tmp/tmp old im typing with cellphone god

Comment: Sorry for being a moron, I promise I'll learn from this. You sir, are a hero. <3

Comment: You must accept it if it solves ur problem. For my hard typing.  I hate iPhone !!!

Answer (score 2):

One call to `awk` is sufficient (and `grep` is unnecessary):

```
system_profiler SPDisplaysDataType | awk '/Resolution/ {
    print "screenwidth \""$2"\"";
    print "screenheight \""$4"\"";
}'
```